# CSS clip / clip-path equivalent

Tags: css

I have a line in my CSS file:

```
clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
```

I see that `clip` is now depreciated, so I am attempting to use `clip-path`. What is `clip-path`'s equivalent?

Is it:

```
clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
```

Comment: "*Is it: `clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);`*" - did you *try* it before asking, or are you asking because you encountered an error, if so: what was the error? Because the first question you should have discovered for yourself ("no"), and then read some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) to see why, and *then* asked us for help if you didn't understand or couldn't find an equivalence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not `inset(0 0 0 0)`. The old `clip` property's parameters specify the distance at which the clipped rect's corners should be located from `(0,0)` of the box whereas in new `clip-path: inset()` they are points from the top, from right, from bottom and from left.

So, `rect(0 0 0 0)` means all four corners of the clipped rect are at (0,0). Whereas `inset(0 0 0 0)` would mean the clipped rect's four corners are at (0,0) (100,0) (100,100) (0,100) for a 100px x 100px box. To put simply, `clip: rect(0 0 0 0)` is clip *everything* while `clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0)` is clip *nothing*.

Similarly, `clip: rect(0 10px 10px 0)` would produce a 10px x 10px box and its equivalent in the new syntax would be `clip: inset(0 90px 90px 0)` (if the un-clipped box is 100px by 100px).

(*Note: Just for clarification, non Webkit/Blink browsers do not support CSS `clip-path` fully as yet and so the snippet will not work as expected in those browsers.*)

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellowgreen;
}
.clip {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
}
.clip-path-inset {
  top: 110px;
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
}
.clip-1 {
  top: 220px;
  clip: rect(0 10px 10px 0);
}
.clip-path-inset-1 {
  top: 330px;
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(0 90px 90px 0);
  clip-path: inset(0 90px 90px 0);
}
.clip-path-polygon-1 {
  top: 440px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 10px 0px, 10px 10px, 0px 10px);
  clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 10px 0px, 10px 10px, 0px 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class='clip'>Some text</div> <!-- this won't be visible as it has rect(0 0 0 0) -->

<div class='clip-path-inset'>Some text</div> <!-- this will be fully visible as it has inset(0 0 0 0)-->

<div class='clip-1'>Some text</div> <!-- this will show a 10px x 10px box -->

<div class='clip-path-inset-1'>Some text</div> <!-- this will show a 10px x 10px box -->

<div class='clip-path-polygon-1'>Some text</div> <!-- this will show a 10px x 10px box -->
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't do anything in Mozilla.

Comment: @MrLister: FF doesn't support CSS clip-path as far as I can remember and I didn't even include the standard version :)

Comment: Firefox has partial support (only using the `url()` syntax) according to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path).

Comment: @DavidThomas: I am not sure if you were responding to my comment or Mr Lister's. The `url()` syntax is outside of this question and hence I didn't mention about that. The point was to show that `clip: rect(0 0 0 0)` and `inset(0 0 0 0)` are not the same.

Comment: Sort of a generic reply to both of you, explanation to Mr Lister and expanding on your own response. I recognised - though didn't state - that `url()` was not necessarily relevant to either this question or answer though.