# CSS clip wont work on a select box?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, clip

I want to clip this select box:

```
<select>
   <option value="">select year</option>    
   <option value="1960">1960</option>   
   <option value="1961">1961</option>   
   <option value="1962">1962</option>
</select>
```

This is my css code:

```
select {
  position:absolute;
  clip:rect(1px,1px,5px,5px);
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;
}
```

but the whole element is rendered invisible. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `clip` does work for `select` element but you have given the values wrongly (and as very small). The values (top, right, bottom and left) specify offsets from the inside top border edge  of the box and the offset for right and bottom should always be more than that for left and top for the clip to work.

The parameters that are provided as input to this function should be read as follows:

- The top side of the clipped box is 1px from the top  side of the original box
- The right side of the clipped box is 5px from the left side of the original box
- The bottom side of the clipped box is  5px from the top side of the original box
- The left side of the clipped box is 1px from the left side of the original box.

So, your clipped box would be a rectangle with the edges (top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left) at (1,1) (5,1) (5,5) (1,5).

Below is a sample snippet. (**Note:** that the value should be large enough for you to see something. In the below snippet you'd only see a 4 x 4 square with just the background color).

```css
select {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(1px, 5px, 5px, 1px);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="">select year</option>
  <option value="1960">1960</option>
  <option value="1961">1961</option>
  <option value="1962">1962</option>
</select>
```

If you want to just clip out the arrow then you could use the parameters provided in the below snippet. But do note that the parameters will depend on the width and height of the content. If content is wider or taller, it would have to be changed.

```css
select {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0px, 75px, 20px, 0px);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="">select year</option>
  <option value="1960">1960</option>
  <option value="1961">1961</option>
  <option value="1962">1962</option>
</select>
```

---

Also, note that the `clip` ***property has been deprecated*** and it is better to use `clip-path` property. The `clip-path` equivalent is available in the below snippet. You can read more about the differences between these two properties in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362776/css-clip-clip-path-equivalent/37362931#37362931).

**Note:** `clip-path` is currently supported only by WebKit (and with `url` property by Firefox). But this is the way forward.

```css
select {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(1px calc(100% - 5px) calc(100% - 5px) 1px);
  clip-path: inset(1px calc(100% - 5px) calc(100% - 5px) 1px);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="">select year</option>
  <option value="1960">1960</option>
  <option value="1961">1961</option>
  <option value="1962">1962</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess the coordinates still confuse me. I just wanted to take out the arrow box and this seems to do it: rect(0px, 70px, 30px,0px). I didnt know clip was deprecated which is bad news since clip-path is not well supported yet.

Comment: @CainNuke: You should read the coordinates like this - the top side of the clipped box is 0px from top of the actual box, the right side is at 70px from the left side of the actual box, the bottom side is 30px from the top of the actual box, the left edge is 0px from the left side of the actual box. So you kind of get a clipped box that is 70px wide and 30px tall. I hope that clarifies. If it does, please consider accepting the answer. If it doesn't, please let me know how further I can help :)

Comment: Yes, I think I got it now. Thank you again.

Comment: Thats great. If you can help me out with my other unanswered question I will appreciate it too.

Comment: I did see that in the morning but unfortunately I don't think I have an answer to that :(

Comment: You mean the one for multiple clip-path polygons?

Comment: Thats a pity. But nevermind, thank you for your help with the other ones.

Comment: Got it. I will do so. Thank you.